# Managing a pointer with a singleton during construction?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm a hobby c++ programmer and it's my first post.

First of all, let me tell you that I'm working on cross-platform ansi C++.

I've just been doing a lot of work figuring out memory management and I've finally gotten the hang of using std::vector and managing my pointers manually during deletion.

Also, I've been using boost::smart_ptr and it has finally clicked.

However I just came across some code where we would have a class Foo who's constructor registers itself with FooManager (A singleton)

```
Foo::Foo()
{
 FooManager::Instance()->register(this);
}
```

During destruction of FooManager, it iterates over a std::vector and applies the erase and delete on each element, effectively cleaning out the memory of Foo.

```
FooManager::~FooManager()
{
    // iterate over the container of Foo pointers
    // erase the pointer from container and delete the pointer
}
```

I was confused because we are not a) using boost::smart_ptr to wrap the pointer during the creation and b) we are using memory management tricks in constructors and destructors.

Is this a viable solution or are there terrible dangers involved with using the destructor of a singleton to clean out the objects that it manages?

From my own tests, I discovered one fundamental drawback. Foo SHOULD NOT be allocated on the stack anymore. The object dereferences itself when it goes out of scope. When the FooManager's destructor is called it tries deleting it again. This generates an assert error:

_ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));

Is that the only drawback? Should I move registration with the manager outside of the Foo constructor? Should I have a seperate function of the FooManager that cleans out the memory which I call manually at the end of my program's lifespan? What are your thoughts on this matter?

Comment: If you need to create a Singleton, use a Myers Singleton. http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/C-plus-plus-In-Theory-The-Singleton-Pattern-Part-I/

Comment: Why dont you un-register in your Foo destructor ?

Comment: You have used smart pointers, so make it a vector of smart pointers.

Does your singleton ever get destructed (aside from when the program exits)?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've been using the Gamma singleton model using a private static. I'll take a look how the Myers will improve my code.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems:

1. The singleton instance of FooMananger is a static variable and has a lifespan from the beginning to the end of the program. if we only delete Foo in FooManager's destructor, which may only be called at the end the program, then we are not doing any memory management at all. it is equivalent to never deleting any Foo instances. isn't it?
2. As you already figured out, the way FooManager register **pointer** inside Foo's constructor, makes it impossible to allocate Foo objects on the stack. you end up with a pointer pointing to invalid memory location, or somewhere you are not supposed to touch.

The common practice is to use smart pointers, depends on your needs, you can use boost::shared_ptr, or boost::scoped_ptr, std::uniqe_ptr (c++11), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Tangentially, I think that the design of your classes is a bit asymmetrical:

1. all Foo objects register themselves at creation time;
2. the FooManager drops all registrations **and** deletes all registered Foo objects upon its deletion.

The problem is: is FooManager just aggregating Foo objects or it is also handling their life cycle?

- If FooManager is only providing an aggregation for Foo objects, then it should not delete them when it is destroyed, because it does not "own" them; a simple internal deregistration should suffice (note: there might be problems in multi-threaded programs).
- If FooManager should have a tighter control on Foo objects (i.e., handle their entire life cycle), a [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) might be more appropriate: only the FooManager can allocate Foo objects.